# Unable to remove/toggle class of element back to `is-inactive`

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, addclass, removeclass

## Where I'm at

After selecting a hockey player, which is denoted by switching their default `is-inactive` class to `is-active`. I'm also adding a class of `full` to prevent players with a class of `picked.is-inactive` from being selected.

## Issue

I'm unable to click on a player a second time with a class of `picked.is-active` once the maximum number of players (two out of four goalies, six out of fifteen defencemen and twelve out of thirty-one forwards) in that category has been reached in order to "deselect" a player and switch their class back to the default `is-inactive` and then choose another player.

*To solve this problem I feel like I need a .removeClass() and an if-else statement of sorts inside my function?*

### scripts.js

```
    /*-------------------------------------
    COUNT SELECTED
    --------------------------------------*/

    function countSelected() {
        $(".player").on("click", function(){

            // Checks if the maximum number of players have been selected
            // If so, return false and then do nothing
            // If not, the class will toggle from `is-inactive` to `is-active`
            if ($(this).find(".picked.full").length > 0) return false;
            $(this).find(".picked").toggleClass("is-inactive is-active");

            // Count the number of players with stars
            var starredGoaltenders = $(".player--goalie").find(".picked.is-active").length;
            var starredDefencemen = $(".player--defencemen").find(".picked.is-active").length;
            var starredForwards = $(".player--forward").find(".picked.is-active").length;

            console.log(starredGoaltenders, starredDefencemen, starredForwards);

            // The number of starred players for each position cannot exceed the following numbers
            var maxGoaltenders = 2;
            var maxDefencemen = 6;
            var maxFowards = 12;

            // If the number of starred players hits its max, a class of `is-completed` is adding to the corresponding checkmark to indicate that the task has been completed
            if (starredGoaltenders === maxGoaltenders) {
                $(".checkmark--goalie").addClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--goalie").find(".picked").addClass("full");
            }

            if (starredDefencemen === maxDefencemen) {
                $(".checkmark--defencemen").addClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--defencemen").find(".picked").addClass("full");
            }

            if (starredForwards === maxFowards) {
                $(".checkmark--forward").addClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--forward").find(".picked").addClass("full");
            }

            // If all the conditions are met show the submit vote button
            if (starredGoaltenders === maxGoaltenders && starredDefencemen === maxDefencemen && starredForwards === maxFowards) {
                $(".btn--submit").show();
                $(".btn--submit").addClass("slideLeft");
            }
        });
} countSelected();
```

### index.html

```
<div class="player player--goalie year--1970">
                    <div class="tooltip tooltip--tall">
                        <p class="tooltip__name">Glen Hanlon</p>
                        <p class="tooltip__hometown"><span>Hometown:</span> Brandon, Man.</p>
                        <p class="tooltip__years"><span>Years Played:</span> 1974-1977</p>
                        <div class="tooltip__stats--inline">
                            <div class="stats__group stats--games">
                                <p class="stats__header">GP</p>
                                <p class="stats__number--games">172</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="stats__group stats--goalsag">
                                <p class="stats__header">GA</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">4.22</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">3.99</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--goalsag">3.09</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="stats__group stats--savep">
                                <p class="stats__header">SAV%</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">.892</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">.891</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--savep">.906</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="stats__group stats--shutouts">
                                <p class="stats__header">SO</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">0</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--shutouts">4</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">4</p>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- tooltip__stats--inline -->
                    </div> <!-- tooltip -->
                    <div class="player__headshot player--hanlon">
                        <div class="picked is-inactive"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="player__name">Glen Hanlon</p>
                    <p class="player__position">Goalie</p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `return false` when class `full` exists but you don't remove it when number of selections is not full.

Try doing `return false` like this:

```
if ($(this).find(".picked.is-inactive.full").length > 0) return false;
```

And do `else` to `removeClass` like this

```
$(".player--goalie").find(".picked").removeClass("full");
```

Full example here https://jsfiddle.net/5pq8z54z/

Comment: Worked like a charm. Hoping you could elaborate a little more about the edits you made to the if-statement

Comment: Adding `.is-inactive` in `find` enables setting element as inactive on second click for active elements. Because otherwise it would return false on active elements also so you couldn't deactivate it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the classes 'is-completed' and 'full' from the player and hide the submit button:

```js
    /*-------------------------------------
    COUNT SELECTED
    --------------------------------------*/

    function countSelected() {
        $(".player").on("click", function(){

            // Checks if the maximum number of players have been selected
            // If so, return false and then do nothing
            // If not, the class will toggle from `is-inactive` to `is-active`
            if ($(this).find(".picked.full").length > 0) return false;
            $(this).find(".picked").toggleClass("is-inactive is-active");

            // Count the number of players with stars
            var starredGoaltenders = $(".player--goalie").find(".picked.is-active").length;
            var starredDefencemen = $(".player--defencemen").find(".picked.is-active").length;
            var starredForwards = $(".player--forward").find(".picked.is-active").length;

            console.log(starredGoaltenders, starredDefencemen, starredForwards);

            // The number of starred players for each position cannot exceed the following numbers
            var maxGoaltenders = 2;
            var maxDefencemen = 6;
            var maxFowards = 12;

            // If the number of starred players hits its max, a class of `is-completed` is adding to the corresponding checkmark to indicate that the task has been completed
            if (starredGoaltenders === maxGoaltenders) {
                $(".checkmark--goalie").addClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--goalie").find(".picked").addClass("full");
            }else{
                $(".checkmark--goalie").removeClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--goalie").find(".picked").removeClass("full");
            }

            if (starredDefencemen === maxDefencemen) {
                $(".checkmark--defencemen").addClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--defencemen").find(".picked").addClass("full");
            }else{
                $(".checkmark--defencemen").removeClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--defencemen").find(".picked").removeClass("full");
            }

            if (starredForwards === maxFowards) {
                $(".checkmark--forward").addClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--forward").find(".picked").addClass("full");
            }else{
                $(".checkmark--forward").removeClass("is-completed");
                $(".player--forward").find(".picked").removeClass("full");
            }

            // If all the conditions are met show the submit vote button
            if (starredGoaltenders === maxGoaltenders && starredDefencemen === maxDefencemen && starredForwards === maxFowards) {
                $(".btn--submit").show();
                $(".btn--submit").addClass("slideLeft");
            }else{
                $(".btn--submit").removeClass("slideLeft");
                $(".btn--submit").hide();                
            }
        });
} countSelected();
```